# Select Dates from datapickers according to the member levels and priority

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have various levels to select dates from datepicker with respect to the priority assigned to the customers below is bit explaination

```
   Member with level 1 can select dates from today till 5 more upcoming days 
   member with level 2 can select till 10 th days from now
   member with level 5 can select till next months days from now
```

here is my code 
can any1 help me to achieve this functionlity

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        new JsDatePick({
            useMode:2,
            target:"inputField",
            limitToToday:false,
            dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
            /*selectedDate:{                This is an example of what the full configuration offers.
                day:5,For full documentation about these settings please see the full version of the code.
                month:9,
                year:2006
            },
            yearsRange:[1978,2020],
            limitToToday:false,
            cellColorScheme:"beige",
            dateFormat:"%m-%d-%Y",
            imgPath:"img/",
            weekStartDay:1*/
        });
    };
```

I am using this plugin

http://javascriptcalendar.org/javascript-date-picker.php

Comment: Use other plugin which suits you..

Comment: here code is required i.e logic
plugin is properly choosen 
i expect some professionals answer rather like bikash chandra's useless answer

Comment: @surajmishra if you are using a plugin then why you want to edit. You will get another better plugin. Just google it.....

Comment: Why edit it, isn't easier to  load those properties on a associative array on php and do something like yearsRange: <?= $user["Range"] ?> and this range is created using that rule above

Comment: please read the question properly there is member level selection which is not available in google thats why i have posted to get the support here .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try DatePicker Widget from jQuery UI. Where we have an option named "maxDate" using which we can set maximum selectable date. For More info please visit [http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate"](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate%22)

And please try to include the option you tried to fix the issue you faced.